# How to display the stock don't hv place order?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The LOST STARTS album is not place order in QTY_ORDERALBUM so it give me NULL, I want to return the stock of the album.

[image]

This is my query below:

```
SELECT    G_ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
          G_ALBUM.ALBUM_QTY - (SUM(G_ORDERALBUM.QTY_ORDERALBUM)) AS STOCK_LEFT
FROM      G_ALBUM 
INNER JOIN G_ARTIST
ON        G_ALBUM.ARTIST_ID = G_ARTIST.ARTIST_ID
FULL OUTER JOIN G_ORDERALBUM
ON        G_ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = G_ORDERALBUM.ALBUM_ID
WHERE     ARTIST_NAME= '&ARTIST_NAME' 
GROUP BY  G_ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME, 
          G_ALBUM.ALBUM_QTY,
          G_ORDERALBUM.QTY_ORDERALBUM;
```

Comment: What you want it to return?

Comment: Can you set up a small data sample and what it should return from it please?

Comment: Hmmm, why are you using `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of simple LEFT JOIN then?

Comment: Ok, I will prepare you given setup and try to see what it is wrong. Though, You should add this setup into your question. Just edit it. And then delete your comments.

Comment: I think I just find the problem, of course depending on how your table are created. According your insert statements the QTY_ORDERALBUM is a varchar and you are using a SUM function on it. Is it right? You need to make it number

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out. Essentially your problem is that you are trying to SUM a column that is returning null,  therefore your problem NULL is not a value it is a state so you can't do math operations on it.

Try your query this way:

```
SELECT G_ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME,
       G_ALBUM.ALBUM_QTY - (SUM(NVL(G_ORDERALBUM.QTY_ORDERALBUM,0))) AS STOCK_LEFT
  FROM G_ALBUM
          INNER JOIN G_ARTIST
            ON G_ALBUM.ARTIST_ID = G_ARTIST.ARTIST_ID
          LEFT JOIN G_ORDERALBUM
            ON G_ALBUM.ALBUM_ID = G_ORDERALBUM.ALBUM_ID
 WHERE G_ARTIST.ARTIST_NAME='&ARTIST_NAME' 
 GROUP BY G_ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME, 
          G_ALBUM.ALBUM_QTY;
```

The NVL function will convert the NULL value to 0. This query should return you:

```
   Big World               0
   Lost Stars              10
   These Old Traditions    5
```

So for the provided inserts you have this data (just for the IDs):

```
G_ALBUM     G_ORDERALBUM
 1003          1003
 1025          1003
 1024          1003
               1025
```

The LEFT JOIN operation will give your this combination:

```
1003 - 1003
1003 - 1003
1003 - 1003
1025 - 1025
1024 - NULL
```

So as you can see the last registry does not have a correspondent row in the table G_ORDERALBUM and therefore your `SUM(G_ORDERALBUM.QTY_ORDERALBUM)` was doing a `SUM(NULL)` for that row.

The [NVL function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) converts a NULL/Empty value into the given parameter

So when the result of `G_ORDERALBUM.QTY_ORDERALBUM` is NULL for the `1024` ID the NVL will replace it by 0 wich will work with you math operation.

Comment: That's correct and good job dude, sorry for my bad english let you cannot know what is the problem since early. Work like a charm! what is the meaning of NVL? can explain (SUM(NVL(G_ORDERALBUM.QTY_ORDERALBUM,0))) ?
Finally I gt the return of the value of These Old Traditions album.
Thanks you!

Comment: I will add a little explanation to the NVL.

Comment: Done, hope you understand.

Comment: Correct correct, now I understand, it's okay, You given a very good explanation and clearly about what I want to ask, appreciate for explain and sharing knowledge. Cheer~~~my query works! Thank you